# Apache Sqoop 2 - User Guide documentation

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I am currently learning Apache Sqoop and I intend to give the HortonWorks certification exam.

One of the exam objectives is to Import data from a table in a relational database into HDFS.

The command to this is SQOOP-IMPORT. I found this command in Sqoop 1 (v 1.4.x) documention (user guide), but I did not find this in Sqoop 2 documentation (v 1.99.x) (user guide).

I also find the documentation for Sqoop 2 to be very confusing.

Can anyone point me to the page where I can find all the Sqoop commands?

Answer (score 0):

Hortonworks does not have Sqoop2, and Cloudera really doesn't seem to support it anymore.

Sqoop2 is a web server with a REST API, not a cli tool with an import command